# How to declare an empty 2-dimensional array in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

Can somebody please tell me how to declare a new instance of a 2-dimensional array?
Most of the languages use something like:

```
array = Array.new[2][2]
```

I don't know how to do it in Ruby.

Comment: That would be quite tedious if he wanted the height and width to be 1000, for example.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can do:

```
width = 2
height = 3
Array.new(height){Array.new(width)} #=> [[nil, nil], [nil, nil], [nil, nil]]
```

Comment: Traditionally arrays are layed out in row major order, ie `[row, row row]`. So your example should swap height and width so that it's like this: `Array.new(height){Array.new(width)}`. That way you can access an element using `arrayInstance[row][column]` instead of `arrayInstance[column][row]`

Answer (score 11):

To declare 2d array in ruby, Use following syntax with initialization value

```
row, col, default_value = 5, 4, 0
arr_2d = Array.new(row){Array.new(col,default_value)}
=> [[0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

We can do any level of nesting, like for 3d array(5 x 4 x 2): you can pass block to initialize array in most inner Array

```
z = 2
arr_3d = Array.new(row){Array.new(col){Array.new(z){|index| index}}}
=> [[[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]], 
    [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]], 
    [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]], 
    [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]], 
    [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]]
```

Now, you can access its element using [] operator like arr_2d[0][1], `actually its array of arrays`

Comment: Didn't know you could specify a default element for an array.  So you can specify the inner array as the default for the outer array too:

s = Array.new(3, Array.new(3, true))
 => [[true, true, true], [true, true, true], [true, true, true]]

Oh, no, you can't.  The same array is used for each row. Fail.

Comment: Use {} instead of () while declaring the inner array, it will work

Answer (score 4):

You could also initialize passing a value:

```
Array.new(3) { Array.new(3) { '0' } }
```

Output:

```
[
 ["0", "0", "0"], 
 ["0", "0", "0"], 
 ["0", "0", "0"]
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a multidimensional array in Ruby with:

`Array.new(Number_of_ROWs){Array.new(Number_of_COLUMNs)}`

**How To Use This Syntax**

Let us understand it by using above example i.e. *`array = Array.new[2][2]`*.

So, in this example we've to declare an empty multidimensional array with 2 rows and 2 column.

Let us start implementing the our syntax now,

`array = Array.new(2){Array.new(2)}`

Now you've an `array` with `2` rows and `2` column with `nil` values.

Now the `array` variable contains `[[nil, nil], [nil, nil]]`  which is consider as an `empty multidimensional array` or `nil value multidimensional array`.

Answer (score -1):

simply: 
 array = Array.new(8,Array.new(8))

Comment: This doesn't really work.  This would create 8 copies of the same array, but not 8 distinct arrays